# How to fix 'daily request limit' in google analytic php API?

Tags: php, google-api, analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using google analytic php Api for save post views data in db and display data on page.But after few mins my age showing below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception:
{ "error": { "code": 429, "message": "Quota Error: profileId 87377568 has exceeded the daily request limit.", 
"errors": [ { 
"message": "Quota Error: profileId 87377568 has exceeded the daily request limit.", 
 "domain": "global", 
"reason": "rateLimitExceeded" } ],
  "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED" } }
```

And when i checked my today hits on google its showing 9456/50000. Then why i am getting this error.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Do you have other applications that access this View (Profile ID)? Could it be that you exhausted the requests per second and the exception isn't stating that properly? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#core_reporting

Comment: Cache the data so it's not being requested directly from the API each time. Surely it's OK if this data is a few minutes delayed at times?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are hitting the [per profile quota limit](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#reporting_apis) of 10,000 requests/day.

Unfortunately, there is not a way around this limit.

> Note: The 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day or the 10 concurrent requests per view (profile) cannot be increased.